# What's wrong with the intuition that kernel measures similarity between observations?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

Near the middle of page 16 of Andrew Ng's [notes on SVM](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf), he explained an intuitive view of kernel as measuring similarity between observations, but then added the caveat that

> there are things wrong with this intuition, but nevermind

The notes don't really explain what's wrong with this intuition. Does anyone know what he might be referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive view of the kernel as measuring the similarity between observations is necessary for machine learning algorithms to be useful. However, kernels used in practice also need to satisfy formal conditions. Kernel matrix needs to be positive semi-definite so that the optimization objectives of kernelized machine learning algorithms remain convex and can be solved to global optimality.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of it is that the inner product can be viewed as a similarity metric, so you could view a good kernel as inducing a feature space in which the inner product is a *good* similarity metric (as the kernel evaluates the inner product between the images of the datapoints in that feature space).

I think Prof. Ng's point is that it is a similarity metric, but as @AbhinavMaurya mentions (+1), not all functions of two data points are valid kernel functions, so there is a fair bit more to it than just being a similarity metric.